# Можно ли назначить кнопке на Google Sheet скрипт из внешнего файла?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

В книге Spreadsheet можно назначить макрос, сохраненный в этой книге, на кнопку на листе.
Можно ли назначить кнопке макрос с внешнего скрипт-файла на гугл диске?

---

Я начинающий в этом деле и не могу разобраться, в чем проблема.
Создал новую папку на гугл-диске, в ней новая гугл-таблица и файл скрипта.

В файле скрипта создал макрос:

```
function testScript() {
  const ss =     SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEbYIW3Bxqx44YmUyu59MGQr3H4dGo7LUiaMoppaDbI/edit?usp=sharing');        
   let a = ss.getRange('A1').getValue()
   Logger.log(a + ' Button1 is pressed.')
}
```

Он запросил разрешения для доступа и работает.

в файле книги импортировал его как библиотеку и создал макрос для ее вызова:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function press_button1() {
  standaloneScript.testScript()
};
```

При его выполнении возникает ошибка
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
testScript  @ Код.gs:2

Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы изменить файл манифеста, используйте [этот](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests?hl=ru) гайд.
После вам нужно добавить необходимое разрешение, должно получиться вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: Спасибо,  это работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это через механизм библиотек https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Главное в этом деле понять, что модульность в облачном пространстве достигается иначе и ожидать безшовного импорта не стоит.

Если ваша кодовая база по-тихоньку превращается в швейцарский нож или фреймворк, то стоит задуматься до версионировании и репозитарном хранении, а код публиковать через API.

Comment: Подключил библиотеку, назначил на кнопку скрипт
function button_spysaty(){
  SkladScript.spysaty()
}
 При выполнении получаю Exception: У вас немає дозволів, щоб телефонувати користувачу SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Потрібні дозволи: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
 Как получать эти разрешения?

Comment: @Михаил, проверьте манифест основного проекта. Там не должно быть ничего, кроме обязательных полей. Это уже другая ошибка.

Comment: Где искать манифест?

Comment: Там же где и лучший ответ.